# Get type containing only own properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
class TestClass {
    readonly firstProperty: number;

    readonly secondProperty: string;

    constructor() {
        this.firstProperty = 5;
        this.secondProperty = 'test';
    }

    logProperties() {
        console.log(this.firstProperty);
        console.log(this.secondProperty);
    }
}

const instance = new TestClass(),
instanceSpread = { ...instance, anotherProperty: 'hello' };
```

Now let's suppose I want to use `instanceSpread` as argument of a function. How should I declare its type? Using `TestClass & { anotherProperty: string }` won't work because `instanceSpread` does not have TestClass methods. I know I can create my own type by copying the TestClass properties and use that, but if in the future TestClass gets another 10 properties, I would have to modify my type too. I'm looking for something that would do the type inference automatically.

Comment: Relevant proposal: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726

Comment: That being said, if you ONLY have own properties of your class to be things that aren't functions, you could just filter the functions out: https://tsplay.dev/N9O69W

Comment: This isn't possible in general, but when you spread a specific class the compiler does know which properties are own, so you can just make your type `type InstanceSpread = typeof instanceSpread` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w6pE0m).  So depending on the use case, you'll either want to do something like that, or assume that function-valued props are not own-and-enumerable and vice versa, or possibly just give up and do it a different way. So which of these approaches, if any, works best for you? What kind of answer would you find acceptable?

Comment: Similarly, you could also drop to the expression level and use a function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPgbEm), then get the return type of that function, if you do not want to rely on creating an instance first or having the type rely on a variable you will use.

Comment: I will take @vr. first suggestion, I think it is the one that best suits my needs. I like using ```typeof``` as @jcalz suggested, but the problem is that I would have to create the type inside the function where ```instanceSpread``` is created, and I cannot export it if I need it in another class (which it's the case). Thank you both!

Comment: Can you explain why the [second](https://tsplay.dev/WPgbEm) one doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered "extends"? Maybe I'm not understanding the question? But I think "extends" would answer your question.

```
class TestClass {
    readonly firstProperty: number;

    readonly secondProperty: string;

    constructor() {
        this.firstProperty = 5;
        this.secondProperty = 'test';
    }

    logProperties() {
        console.log(this.firstProperty);
        console.log(this.secondProperty);
    }
}

class TestClassAdvanced extends TestClass {
   anotherProperty = 'hello'
}

instance = new TestClass()
instanceSpread = new TestClassAdvanced()
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but creating a new class just for one object created from a spread is too overkill for me. Thanks though

Comment: Understood, but yes, but that's Typescript. I suppose the details of what you're doing matter, so maybe there's another path for you. I don't find it that bad in practice. And of course there's always the "any" type which can be very useful for times when you want to ignore type. There's also constructs like "Map()".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible without dropping down to the expression level, since using the spread syntax is the only way to get TypeScript to respect enumerability of properties. Like [jcalz suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857953/get-type-containing-only-own-properties-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment133806268_75857953), you could use `typeof instanceSpread` as the type, but another similar idea would be to use a function, taking its return type as the type of a spread instance:

```
const _enumerableTestClass = (t: TestClass) => ({ ...t });
type EnumerableTestClass = ReturnType<typeof _enumerableTestClass>;
```

`EnumerableTestClass` now holds `{ firstProperty: number; secondProperty: string; }`, exactly what we were looking for, and it does work for annotating `instanceSpread`:

```
const instanceSpread: EnumerableTestClass & { anotherProperty: string } = {
    ...instance,
    anotherProperty: "hello",
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QCd4wATAewDsQBPaAMwEsDkAFAsgB3gKWoC5oFAK4BbAEbcA3Nlz4ipSjWgR4wSiTaduvAcgIMKAc2my8ainqHAkZAgAoAlFlP48SABYMIAOkbMkmlw8tAC80ACs0q6uHl7eKuYa7EG80GEAREiISOlR+AC+Mq4gZIaB2gyIjs7R+OYQZCDw3iWGdrE+fqzJ2tQOebX1jc2t7Z4+Cerlwf0uhYXY9UjQBshgFMDwaYLwAO5w2WiQEI4mS9AA+vDCItxgYk0IyEcYYe0CT6joEE4hAHzQOyYaDeUHLfKzXhcaAAURudwe8E+LxgYQASvAkEICBRYNQuAAeKHwMh0S7XUQIx6Hb5-EyLSjIFYWJDrTYAZQ48hIAjhlII92pz2+0AAZFhoOsyB5uNMdMokPojNB8tscK5Qd5VqyNvAADQuKUyghy-jQdLueAgErpA35aRAA)

---

If your class's properties are never functions (and all your class's methods are defined on the prototype), then in theory, you could simply filter out functions:

```
type FilterFuncs<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never : K]: T[K] };
```

This, intersected with the added property, seems to match the type of the spread:

```
// okay
const instanceSpread: FilterFuncs<TestClass> & { anotherProperty: string } = { ...instance, anotherProperty: 'hello' };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoaB0ATvGACYD2AdiAJ7QBmAlkcgApEUAO8RStALmhUArgFsARrwDcePIWKlKNehHjBqZDt178hyIkyoBzWbnmENVAyOBIKRABQBKLBYUEkACyYQAdMysSNo8fPQAvNAArGYehN6+fmpWWpyh-NCRAORIiEhZsYQAvnL4hCAUxiG6TIgubmVxVhAUIPB+FcaOCf6B7Gm6tM6FTdQtbR2V3T7+yZrVYcPu0CW4q3jNSNBGyGBUwPCZwvAA7nB5aJAQLmZ4-DzQAGJMILlEjyL7EAA8sAB8R0w0AA2gBpbZUaAAa3gtAoDDg0EgcDBAF1oPAAB65KhkGCOPyEsBEYwQIR7WjA1GucIAinQAD8xwAbrxoEJQaihLA0StbrgAPQC6AUKFgWgbMZbHZIPYHADKXBI5CEz1evA+X1+F3QEABADIsEiqBRvLwFnpoAYjMYVoDoIS-DK5fAADTG01ec0DMJCLJekAVLJ8oA)